# Changing counter's value on button click

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, button

I've been searching for a while, and I found that I can send a value from doGet to html created.

But I want to do smth different, I want to have a button and label where where every time I press on that button it increments the label.

something like a counter for pressing that button.

I already has the HTML that renders button and label it's pretty simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <?!= include('stylesheet'); ?>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>LDP Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
     function incrementCounter() {}
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <label> Counter 0 </label>
  <button onClick="incrementCounter"> Increment counter</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to link the incrementCounter function to this label, or whatever html element that can be done that whenever the button is pressed it gets incremented and rendered on the screen
can someone guide me to go through this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code. Firstly it should be `onclick` not `onClick` and the function should be called as `onclick="incrementCounter()"`.

Secondly, a label should be used with a input, textarea or select element.

Now coming to the code

**HTML**

```
<p>Count: <span id="counter">0<span></p>

<button onclick="incrementCounter()">Increment Counter</button>
```

**JS**

```
function incrementCounter() {
   const counterElem = document.querySelector('#counter'),
         count = +counterElem.innerHTML;
   counterElem.innerHTML = count+1;
}
```

What is happening inside the code is I'm selecting the target element where the count would display. Then I'm getting the value of its innerHTML and parsing it as an integer using `+` before the `counterElem.innerHTML`. Then I'm adding 1 to the value and setting it as the innerHTML

Comment: Thanks a lot, but you gotta change counterElem.innerHTML to counterElem.innerText
as innerHTML will produce NaN error as this is what returned from it '0<span></span>'
but innerText will return '0' only

Comment: Actually no. If you look carefully the id `counter` is assigned to the span element. So it won't return NaN

Comment: I got your point, but when I tested it, this was the error I got and I had to change it to innerText and it works .. maybe the hierarchy that I've changed something that made it this way.